# jupyter notebook starting error

Tags: python, anaconda

### I am facing the following error while starting jupyter-notebook. Anyone has any idea what's wrong?

```
desk ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages $ jupyter-notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suny/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "/home/suny/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 28, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "/home/suny/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    _patch_async()
  File "/home/suny/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 77, in _patch_async
    from jinja2.asyncsupport import patch_all
  File "/home/subinoy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 13, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/home/suny/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/home/suny/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 17, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "/home/suny/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/home/suny/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 355
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did  you try `jupyter notebook` instead of `jupyter-notebook`?

Comment: Looks like the backport of `futures` has been installed, e.g. `pip3 install futures`, this isn't necessary in Py3 as this already has the modules in the standard library. Try: `pip3 uninstall futures` and see if it works.

Comment: Using jupyter notebook give me same error as above and I don't have pip3 installed so I tried with pip uninstall futures ubinoy@suny-desk ~ $ pip uninstall futures
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/subinoy/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 4, in <module>
    import pip
  File "/home/subinoy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/home/subinoy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/......
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._tracebacke

Comment: Can I manually remove the package folder from the sitepackage??